# Return Parameter From SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a sql stored procedure and return a value from the query.  My syntax throws the error of:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to 'decimal'

This is my syntax, what should I alter in order to have this run properly?

```
public Decimal ReturnValueFromQuery(string connectionString, string sqlQuery, int blah, DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString].ToString();
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", SqlDbType.Int).Value = blah;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = d2;
        var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return returnParameter;
    }
}
catch { }
}
```

Comment: Error message say it all

Comment: If you can't implicitly convert something, normally explicitly converting it works (if the data tied to it is compatible anyways).

Comment: Do an explicit conversion to decimal of the value returned from SQL.

Comment: Could you add also the code of the StoredProcedure? If you want to return a decimal you cannot use ParameterDirection.ReturnValue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method says that it will return a decimal, writing `return returnParameter` is not possible because it doesn't respect the signature of your method.

You should convert the `Value` property of the return parameter to a decimal value

```
return Convert.ToDecimal(returnParameter.Value);
```

However I have some perplexities about your choice to use a parameter with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. As you have correctly written (`SqlDbType.Int`) these parameters can return only integers not decimals. Perhaps, you should consider a parameter with `ParameterDirection.Output` and pass it in the calling list of the stored procedure

Of course if you have really an integer then there is also the possibility to change your method return value to an int.
And finally I strongly suggest to remove any empty catch block. These blocks are deadly when you have an exception because you never know anything about it.

Comment: Good catch on the return type definition.  Only reason I could really think of that might make sense is if the return value is then being passed into some other function that gets used elsewhere but expects a decimal value to be passed to it..  (EDIT: That being said, it should really be overloaded if that's actually what's going on...)

Comment: In any case if he really wants to return a decimal he is at risk to loose information with this choice. (The decimal part will be lost)